# Recursive formula for word problem.

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I'm having problems with this recursion problem: Ann wants to buy along several weeks one dressing item which can be of two kinds: small ones -- hats and scarfs, and big ones -- dresses, suits, gowns and coats. There exists one unique restriction: she cannot buy two big items in two weeks in a row. Write down a recursive sequence that represents the numbers of possible different purchases she can do in n weeks.

My idea: we have that $\;a_1= 6\;,\;\;a_2=2\cdot 6+4\cdot2=20\;$

Now, doing some cumbersome arithmetics, I reach $\;a_3=88\,$ , but I can't see what the recursion is.

If you can help me to understand thank you

Comment: Yes Andre, that is true. Thank very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a_k$ be the number of allowed ("good") purchase sequences in $k$ weeks. Now look at $a_{n+1}$, the number of good purchase sequences in the first $n+1$ weeks.

The purchase in the $(n+1)$-th week can be of two types (i) Small or (ii) Big. We count the number of sequences each type.

For Type (i), we can append any small purchase to any good purchase sequence for the first $n$ weeks. Thus there are $2a_n$ good purchase sequences of length $n+1$ that end in a small purchase.

For Type (ii), the purchase sequence for the first $n$ weeks must have ended with a small. And the purchase sequence in the first $n-1$ weeks is unrestricted. Thus the number of Type (ii) sequences of length $n+1$ is $(4)(2)a_{n-1}$.

We have obtained the recurrence $a_{n+1}=2a_n+8a_{n-1}$.

Note that the basic idea is really the same as the one that you used to compute $a_3$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! A little question about type (ii): as the number of purchases in the first $\;n-1\;$ weeks is unrestricted, we have here $\;4a_{n-1}\;$ sequences that end in a "big" purchase on the $\;n-$th week, and then on these one we have $\;2\;$ possibilities for each (as after a big purchase there can only be a small one next week) and we then get $\;2\cdot4\cdot a_{n-1}\;$ for the $\;(n+1)$-th week...arithmetically it doesn't matter, but the order of the coefficients of $\;a_{n-1}\;$ help me to understand better.

Comment: Andre, I cannot upvote your answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: At your suggestion, I will change the order of multiplication, to make the logic more clear to others.  As to no upvote, no problem!

Comment: It is very clear. Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome.